# Fractional index in a chemical formula of metal oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, transition-metals, solid-state-chemistry, nanotechnology

I have just read an article in which they used $\ce{WO3}$ and $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ as precursors, whose objective was to form $\ce{WS2}$, in an atmosphere of argon by CVD. In one boat there is the powder of $\ce{S}$ and in another boat there is $\ce{WO3}$ or $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$, in an oven with a double temperature zone. In the article they conclude that $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ forms larger layers of $\ce{WS2}$ in the substrate giving the following justification:

> They found that $\ce{W^6+}$ cannot be directly sulfated by $\ce{S},$ unless some intermediates are formed due to the high energy of the $\ce{W-O}$ bond. The reduction from $\ce{W^6+}$ to $\ce{W^5+}$ is mandatory for the incorporation of sulfur in the $\ce{WO3}$ network. For $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ in our case, its partial $\ce{W^6+}$ ions have been reduced to $\ce{W^5+}$ or $\ce{W^4+}$ ions. Therefore, we find that replacing $\ce{W^5+}$ or $\ce{W^4+}$ with $\ce{W^6+}$ in the initial stage facilitates the growth of the single crystal $\ce{WS2}$ film.

I didn't realize what the difference is between $\ce{WO3}$ and $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ and where these ions come from that they talk about in this part of the article. I also don't understand what a fractional index means in a chemical formula. Could you help me to interpret that part of the article and explain these doubts that I have please?

Comment: Similar question for W3O8: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65862/oxidation-state-of-tungsten-in-w3o8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about fractional indices in chemistry, it is just a pointer signifying we are dealing with a [non-stoichiometric compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-stoichiometric_compound).
Group 6 metal are known not only for their regular oxides existing in numerous polymorphic modifications, but also for forming homologous series of nonstoichiometric oxides $\ce{\ce{M^{VI}_nO_{3n-1}}}$ and $\ce{\ce{M^{VI}_nO_{3n-2}}}$ with the general formula $\ce{M^{VI}O_{3-x}}$ $(\ce{M} = \ce{Mo}, \ce{W};$ $x \in (0; 1)).$

Now, to make things clear, notation "$\ce{WO_{2.9}}$" *does not* refer to a molecule; $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ is a [formula unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_unit) showing composition of a network solid.
To further illustrate the origin of the fractional coefficients here, let's refer to the crystal structures of the stoichiometric and non-stoichiometric tungsten(VI) oxides $(\ce{WO3}$ and $\ce{WO_{2.9}},$ respectively).

Depending on the temperature, $\ce{WO3}$ adopts several polymorphs with various crystal structures; at the room temperature the most common structure it adopts is the one of distorted $\ce{ReO3}$ type, being made of tilted $\ce{[WO6]}$ octahedra cross-linked via the corners (for the illustration, see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tungsten_trioxide)).

On the other hand, $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ is an oxygen-deficient compound in comparison.
To account for that and eliminate the presence of point defects, crystal structure undergoes a transformation resulting in increased number of edge-sharing groups of $[\ce{WO6}]$ polyhedra and reduced number of the corner-sharing ones, e.g. the structure gets more "packed", and, more importantly, a *crystallographic shear* is introduced (which *is not* an impurity).
Let's have a look at the [asymmetric unit](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Asymmetric_unit) of $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ of the crystal structure determined by Magnéli [[1](https://doi.org/10.1038/165356b0)]:

[image: Asymmetric unit]
**Figure 1.** Crystal structure of $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ [[1](https://doi.org/10.1038/165356b0), ICSD-24736] showing an asymmetric unit $\ce{W10O29}.$ 
Color code: $\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$; $\color{#2194D6}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{W}$.

Due to the asymmetric unit $\ce{W10O29},$ the chemical formula (formula unit) is reduced to $\ce{WO_{2.9}}.$
One can also fill the entire [unit cell](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Unit_cell) knowing the number of formula units $(Z)$ per unit cell; here, $Z = 2$ and this results in equal formula $\ce{W20O58},$ often seen in the literature:

[image: Unit cell]
**Figure 2.** Crystal structure of $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ [[1](https://doi.org/10.1038/165356b0), ICSD-24736] showing packed unit cell.
Color code: $\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$; $\color{#2194D6}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{W}$.

Finally, to illustrate the location of the aforementioned shear plane, let's complete coordination shells on all tungsten atoms and view the structure along the $b$ axis:

[image: Shear plane]
**Figure 3.** Crystal structure of $\ce{WO_{2.9}}$ [[1](https://doi.org/10.1038/165356b0), ICSD-24736] showing polyhedral representation ($[\ce{WO6}]$ octahedra) with the shear plane along $a$ axis denoted with red arrow.
Color code: $\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$; $\color{#2194D6}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{W}$.

As for the assignment of the formal oxidation numbers for the non-stoichiometric compounds like this, this is typically considered a non-trivial task of a questionable value.
Also, see [the answer of mine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/109028/41328) to the related question [Oxidation state of tungsten in $\ce{W3O8}$](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65862/oxidation-state-of-tungsten-in-w3o8).

#### References

1. Magnéli, A. Structure of β-Tungsten Oxide. *Nature* **1950**, 165 (4192), 356–357. DOI: [10.1038/165356b0](https://doi.org/10.1038/165356b0).

Comment: There are also references to a $\ce{W_{18}O_{49}}$ such as [this one](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0040603179850510).  Would this be a combination of $\ce{W_nO_{3n-1}}$ and $\ce{W_nO_{3n-2}}$ with $n=6$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi Judging from the structure ([ICSD 202488](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/structures/Search?Ccdcid=202488&DatabaseToSearch=Published) by [Lamire et al. 1987](http://pascal-francis.inist.fr/vibad/index.php?action=getRecordDetail&idt=7723347)), $\ce{W18O49}$ is a different story: there is a tungsten with C.N. 7 (pentagonal bipyramid, like in many uranium(VI) componds) forming pentagonal assemblies with other $[\ce{WO6}]$ octahedra, which is even more efficient packing (than shear plane) that can afford to account for further O-deficiency.

Comment: Thanks.  One minor point:  "Further O deficiency" seems to be a judgment call.  $\ce{W_{18}O_{49}}$ is less deficient than $\ce{W3O8}$; the latter, on an equal tungsten basis, would be $\ce{W_{18}O_{48}}$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi True, let's just agree on oxygen deficiency.